# Set maximum label width in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, label, width

On a Xamarin.Forms label, I see a MinimumWidthRequest, but is there any way to set the maximum width allowed?

I have a StackLayout with horizontal orientation, and would like labels in the layout to have a maximum width of 500px before being truncated.  I don't want to just set the WidthRequest to 500px, because shorter labels should be sized to fit without extra space at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the label's [`LineBreakMode`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.LineBreakMode/) to `TailTruncation`

If you do not set the `WidthRequest`, it will automatically truncate when the label reaches the end of the container.  This will allow your shorter labels to remain smaller, as you requested.

XAML

```
<Label 
  Text="This is a very long text" 
  LineBreakMode="TailTruncation">
</Label>
```

C#

```
label.LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation;
```

============

- DOCS: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.LineBreakMode/
- EXAMPLE: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20509/truncate-long-texts-with-ellipsis-on-label-control